# Vertical Scrollbar visible but not working CSS

Tags: css

Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:

CSS:

```
outer { 
     width: 100%;
     max-height: 400px;
     margin: 60px auto 0;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     overflow-y:auto;
     line-height: 20px;

     p {
         margin: 0 auto;
         padding-right: 20px;
     }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
     <p>  long text....  <p>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using any css pre processor like sass, less? and it will be great if you will post an example or fiddle of issue.

Comment: I am using Atom 1.7.4.

Answer (score 1):

Plz check you css

```
.outer { width: 100%; max-height: 400px; margin: 120px;overflow-x: hidden;overflow-y:auto; line-height: 20px; }

p { margin: 0 auto;padding-right: 20px;}
```

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand. What should i do to make scrollbar working?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look

```css
.outer {     width: 100%;
    max-height: 400px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    line-height: 20px;
    background: #ccc;
 }

p { margin: 0 auto;padding-right: 20px;}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
 <p>Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:Scrollbar is visible but not working. Following is the code for CSS for display paragraph:</p>
</div>
```

Comment: why 2 answer with less details? and got 2 uv??

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine in my local machine:

```
.outer {    
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 400px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    line-height: 20px;
    background: #ccc;
 }

p { margin: 0 auto;padding-right: 20px;}

<div class="outer">
  <p>pls place scroll content here</p>
</div>
```